# ./mach compilation of thunderbird78 reported an error：'ValueError' object has no attribute 'message'

Tags: compiler-errors

When porting Thunderbird 78 to Loongarch, enter in the root directory/ Mach bootstrap error: 'ValueError' object has no attribute 'message'
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FT8fM.png)

At first, I thought it was a version issue with Python. The message object was not present in higher versions of Python, but after I lowered the version of Python, the result remained unchanged